Lenovo P14s Gen 5 Ubuntu 24.04 Can't Suspend
Lenovo P14s Gen 5 Intel laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 cannot suspend when the lid is closed or when the suspend button is pressed. The system goes blank for a few seconds and then "wakes" into a glitchy state with the mouse pointer jumping, videos lagging, etc. Only a reboot seems to restore normal function.
This is the kernel version:
Linux 6.8.0-49-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov  4 02:06:24 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Any help is reatly appreciated!

We need some log data; attempt the suspend, and then give us the output of sudo journalctl -e

I have a P14s gen 2, and when this happens, it is usually because some program I am running blocks it. Can you suspend normally if you close all open programs? What if you use the UI to choose "suspend" from the shutdown options?

log data: https://pastebin.com/s9knFFwF

this fixed it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1531286/598532
